# jQuery Script: I Populate An Array But Can't Access It From Outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, scope

I'm starting to fiddle with jquery and I'm going kind of crazy... I am making a little script to fetch football players from a fantasy football website. I have the following html and JS to work with:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Jugador</th>
      <th>Equipo</th>
      <th>Puntos</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jugador">
      <td>Sergio-Ramos</td>
      <td>Real Madrid</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jugador">
      <td>Messi</td>
      <td>F.C. Barcelona</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jugador">
      <td>Morales</td>
      <td>Levante</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="jugador">
      <td>Bale</td>
      <td>Real Madrid</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following JS:

```
<script>
  var puntos_jugador = [];

  $(".jugador").each(function(index) {

    var nombre = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();

    puntos_jugador = puntosJugador(nombre);

    console.log(nombre);
    console.log(puntos_jugador);

    $(this).find("td").eq(2).text("Hola");
  });

  function puntosJugador(nombre) {
    var puntos = [];

    $.get('https://www.comuniazo.com/comunio/jugadores/' + nombre, function(response) {

      $(response).find('.tr-points, .tr-status').each(function(fila) {
        //var jornada = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
        var puntos_jornada = $(this).find(".bar").text();
        puntos.push(puntos_jornada);
        //console.log('Jornada ' + jornada + ' ' + puntos);
      });
    });

    return puntos;
  }
</script>
```

The thing is the console.log(puntos_jugador) does return an array filled with the information:

[image]

However I cannot access puntos_jugador[0] or try puntos_jugador.toString() .

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong (maybe everything) or give me some orientation on how to fix this?

Thanks on beforehand and sorry for my low JS level, I'm working on it.

Comment: your puntosJugador() method returns even if $.get is not yet finish. Remember that JavaScript is asynch, so put your return statement inside $.get() call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are doing an asynchronous call with `$.get` and then you return the result directly without waiting for the response, which will always be the empty array define above. 
You should wait for the response and then call a callback (or use promises)

Something like this:

```
  var puntos_jugador = [];

  $(".jugador").each(function(index) {

    var nombre = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();

    puntosJugador(nombre, function(result) {
        console.log('done'); 
        puntos_jugador = result;
        console.log(nombre);
        console.log(puntos_jugador);
    });

    $(this).find("td").eq(2).text("Hola");
  });

  // <---- HERE pass a callback and then call it when you have all results.
  function puntosJugador(nombre, cb) {
    var puntos = [];
    $.get('https://www.comuniazo.com/comunio/jugadores/' + nombre, function(response) {
       console.log('response ',response)
      $(response).find('.tr-points, .tr-status').each(function(fila) {
        //var jornada = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
        var puntos_jornada = $(this).find(".bar").text();
        puntos.push(puntos_jornada);
        //console.log('Jornada ' + jornada + ' ' + puntos);
        console.log('here', puntos);
      });
      cb(puntos);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Refactor your method to this:

```
function puntosJugador(nombre) {
    var puntos = [];

    $.get('https://www.comuniazo.com/comunio/jugadores/' + nombre, function(response) {

      $(response).find('.tr-points, .tr-status').each(function(fila) {
        //var jornada = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
        var puntos_jornada = $(this).find(".bar").text();
        puntos.push(puntos_jornada);
        //console.log('Jornada ' + jornada + ' ' + puntos);
      });
      return puntos;
    });


  }
```

Comment: this will return `undefined` ... check how async works in js